# Passing a hash to a controller with extra parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that the user fills out which contains a title and a body. I also want to pass over their user ID which is stored in a cookie as well as a couple of other calculated values.

In my create section of my controller i have the following code:

```
@ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket])
@ticket.save
redirect_to ticket_path(@ticket)
```

Do I need to assign these calculated values after the Ticket.new call or can I pass these along with the params hash somehow?

Comment: I tried assigning these values after the call to Ticket.new and it worked. Is there a way to include them in that call just to shorten the code a little?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the ticket key of params is just a hash, you can use merge to add additional key/value pairs

```
@ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket].merge({user_id: cookies[:user_id]}))
@ticket.save
redirect_to ticket_path(@ticket)
```

Assuming you are using Active Relation and a `User` `has_many :tickets` you could also do something like this (this example assumes `current_user` is defined by something similar to Devise)

```
@ticket = current_user.tickets.build(params[:ticket])
@ticket.save
redirect_to ticket_path(@ticket)
```

The second way makes it a little clearer what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks Evan. I am new to rails and hadn't run across the build method yet. Looks like it is similar to 'new' but gets called through an existing object using a foreign key. Is that correct?

Comment: No problem. You are correct. `build` is a ActiveRecord::Relation method whereas `new` (in the context you used it) is a Ruby method for creating a new instance of a Class. In recent versions of Rails, `new` is an alias of `build` in ActiveRecord::Relation, so you can use the two interchangeable in the `current_user.tickets` context, but I prefer `build`. There are several good explanations of build vs. new around.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `f.hidden_field` in your form to pass some additional calculated values.

If you want to assign `current_user` to ticket it is better to do it in separate assignment, and keep it protected.

Comment: Would there be an advantage to including it in the form as a hidden field, other than being able to include it in the hash? My only concern is that someone viewing the source could see the user_id.